# Is it normal that Quick S.M.A.R.T test fails after successful repair?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, desktop-computer, smart, bad-sectors

I have two HDD WD7500BPKT and testing them using [WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=3) .

Both of them had bad sectors. Both were successfully "repaired" (with WD Data Lifeguard proposed method).

Then I'm trying to run quick test: one drive reports 'OK', second 'FAILED' (07 as I remember - usual code for bad sectors obtained).

Why there is a difference in quick test results and what does it mean? Should I repeat the extended test and repair HDD till drive the pass quick test or report "too many bad sectors" ?

Should I try other tools that can report with more information?

SMART Attributes that should be important

```
Reallocated_Event_Count
1st 200 200 000 0
2nd 200 200 000 0

Current_Pending_Sector
1st 200 200 000 0
2nd 200 200 000 4

UDMA_CRC_Error_Count
1st 200 200 000 0
2nd 200 200 000 2

Multi_Zone_Error_Rate
1st 196 196 000 748
2nd 200 200 000 2
```

Comment: "Yes" to all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as bad sector repair. Bad sectors tend to grow like a avalanche over time. Remapping of sectors cannot be considered as repairs.

Traffic light type checks are not a replacement for looking at a bunch of SMART parameters of a drive.

Try runnning smartmontools and post a log file here:

run
smartctl -a /dev/sdx >mylog.txt

Replace the letter x by the letter of your drive in question.
Post mylog.txt here!

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I understand the meaning of the repair procedure the same way, as remaping. Here I'm just interesting in explanation (versions) how it is possible: two different results on the same HDD model with the same tool. Should repair (remap) hide bad sectors for quick test or not?  Thank you for the tool recommendation. Going to check it.

Comment: I've added SMART Attributes to the question. But it is strange that quick test now returns ok for both drive. I'm shocked  it is so contrintuitive (nondetermenism in test).

Comment: I don't see the log file.

Comment: I've replaced second HDD (where are bad sectors reported) and have only one report. Thank you for the tool recomendation - report is very impressive. Next time I will examine the difference betweeb them.

Comment: Good luck, thanks for the feedback!